# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.0.0) - "Registered callback does not match with the provided url" in a distributed setup

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm currently using wso2am-4.0.0 and I have 2 separate nodes setup and synced according to the documentation.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/synchronizing-artifacts-in-a-gateway-cluster/#inbuilt-artifact-synchronization

Once I try to login to one of the instances, "Registered callback does not match with the provided url" occurs.

If I change the callback url of the service providers related to the publisher and devportal to the 2nd node's hostname, I cannot login to the 1st node and vice versa.

Any solution for this incident is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use the external hostname in this case. Not the node specific hostname

Answer (score 1):

You need a load balancer in front of the nodes in order to expose a unique DNS name to the web browser